# How to use grep to count no of files in which the given string appears atleast once?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Using the command below i could find the total occurrences of the given string in the current directory.

```
cat * | grep -c 'nike'
```

In the same way, how to get the total count of files in which the given keyword appears atleast once?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep -l Nike * | wc -l

Don't use cat.

Comment: what if i also want to print file names?

Comment: grep -l Nike * |tee /dev/tty |wc -l

Comment: i see that the given string is not matching with the whole keyword. if i search for lincoln it says 0 but the actual count is 40

Comment: Make it `grep -il` if you need it to be case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

grep -l prints only file names

```
grep -l 'nike' * | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

use grep with wc and -l option is for lines.

grep -R "pattern" .|wc -l